# exam document, problem with multiple choice question

Tags: exam

I would like to change evry letter (a), (b), (c), (d)
with a square or a circle. Can you help me?

That's my document (there are many packages because I have to use them).

```
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt] 

\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{natbib} 
%\usepackage{cite} 

\usepackage{subfig}                        

\usepackage{xcolor}

%\usepackage{package}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 

\usepackage{textcomp} 

\linespread{1.5}                %(default=1, MM1 = s1.4)



\frenchspacing 

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}

\usepackage{multicol}


 %\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}

  \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.0cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

%\large 

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{center}
high school
\begin{minipage}{.10\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=0, width=.70\textwidth]
{logo_frisi.png}\\
%\emph{\small Didascalia}\bigskip
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.40\textwidth}
{test}
\end{minipage}


\end{center}

\vspace{0.2in}
\noindent {\makebox[\textwidth]{name:\enspace\hrulefill \, Date:\,\dots/11/15 \, Class:\,1\dots} }

\begin{enumerate}



\item Question 1

\begin{multicols}{2}


\begin{enumerate}


\item Answer 1

 \item Answer 2

 \item Answer 3

 \item Answer 4

 \end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}



\item Question 2?

\begin{multicols}{3}


\begin{enumerate}


\item Answer 1

 \item Answer 2

 \item Answer 3

 \end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}

\item Question 3

\begin{multicols}{2}


\begin{enumerate}


\item Answer 1

 \item Answer 2

 \item Answer 3

 \item Answer 4

 \end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}



\item Question 4

\begin{multicols}{3}


\begin{enumerate}


\item Answer 1

 \item Answer 2

 \item Answer 3

 \end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  %\caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rcccccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Ex} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4}  & \textbf{TOT} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Punti} & 
    \dots\dots/1.0 & 
    \dots\dots/0.75 & 
    \dots\dots/0.75 & 
    \dots\dots/1.5 & 
    \dots\dots/4.0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  %\label{tab:addlabel}%
  %\caption*{min: 2/10}
\end{table}%

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you would better use the exam-class.

Comment: Or AMC (automultiplechoice) if you are a Linux user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[$\square$]
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a comment at most and it lacks some packages or mentioning them and ist perhaps not what the O.P. requested

Comment: it doen't work :(

Comment: @ryuk: Most likely you need `\usepackage{enumerate}` -- but as I wrote in my initial comment: This is perhaps not what you want to have at all

Comment: thank you every one! Now with \usepackage{enumerate} it works! :)

Comment: @ryuk: Well, basically you have an accepted an answer which is none so far ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer this is what ryuk was looking for. If you are telling me to improve my answer as for the style, I'll do it, I'm just a beginner. But I do not see why you are so against a simple solution which is close to the user's needs.

Comment: @Giacomo: Your post does not work so far unless you state `\usepackage{enumerate}` or `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` has to be used -- this is missing in your post, so it doesn't work and is not a solution until improved. It is always better to provide working examples, not just fragments.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I assumed that he knew the package, you're right. Thanks I'll do it straightaway

Comment: @Giacomo: Much better ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank for your support: I'm new to the forum I need to learn the standards.

Comment: actually the first time I have tried to use the package for exam (Philip Hirschhorn
Department of Mathematics
Wellesley College
Wellesley, MA 02481
psh@math.mit.edu)
but it doesn't work well. I don't know why. When I have time i try to post the code with that package.